# In NTFS Compressed Directory, How to read Files compressed and uncompressed size?

Tags: c++, compression, c++builder, ntfs

In our application, we are generating some large ASCII log files to an Windows NTFS compressed directory.  My users want to know both the compressed and uncompressed size of the files on a status screen for the application.  We are using Rad Studio 2010 C++ for this application.

I found this nice recursive routine online to read the size of the files on the disk -

```
__int64 TransverseDirectory(string path)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    __int64 size  = 0;
    string  fname = path + "\\*.*";
    HANDLE  h     = FindFirstFile(fname.c_str(), &data);

    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if ((data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                if (strcmp(data.cFileName, ".") != 0 && strcmp(data.cFileName, "..") != 0)
                {
                    // We found a sub-directory, so get the files in it too
                    fname = path + "\\" + data.cFileName;
                    // recurrsion here!
                    size += TransverseDirectory(fname);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LARGE_INTEGER sz;
                sz.LowPart  = data.nFileSizeLow;
                sz.HighPart = data.nFileSizeHigh;
                size       += sz.QuadPart;
                // ---------- EDIT ------------ 
                if (data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED)
                     {
                       unsigned long doNotCare;
                        fname = path + "\\" + data.cFileName;
                        DWORD lowWordCompressed = GetCompressedFileSize(fname.c_str(),
                        &doNotCare);
                        compressedSize += lowWordCompressed;
                      }
                // ---------- End EDIT ------------ 
            }
        }
        while (FindNextFile(h, &data) != 0);
        FindClose(h);
    }
    return size;
}
```

But what I cannot find is any information on how to read compressed/uncompressed file size information.  Suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Unless the size is stored separately. Then you literally have to use the same logic that uncompresses the file to scan the whole file and read it.

Comment: @Martin - It's not quite doubled.  Yes, you are correct in that you have to do two lookups, but you can add the compressed lookup into the main loop.  I've added my working lookup code into the loop above.  It's not as clean as it should be, but it is something that I only need to run once a minute, so it is good enough for my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Win32 API [GetFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364955%28VS.85%29.aspx) will return the uncompressed file size. The API [GetCompressedFileSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364930%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will return the compressed file size.